# The best way to define union type flag in C++

Tags: c++, unions, memory-alignment, bit-fields

Can I assume that 2 the most first fields with same types in two structs which joined into union to be same?

I want to create container class that keep some elements in stack if it small or keep them in vector. It is like to Small String Optimization.

I develop it like union-like class that described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

And I use bitfield as type flag:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct C {
  bool is_on_stack : 1;
  struct stack_data {
    size_t size : 3;
    int data[(sizeof(std::vector<int>)) / sizeof(int)];
    stack_data() : size(0) {}
  };

  struct heap_data {
    std::vector<int> data;
    heap_data() : data() {}
  };

  union {
    stack_data stack;
    heap_data heap;
  };
  C():stack() {}
  ~C() {
      if(!is_on_stack){
          heap.~heap_data();
      }
  }
};
int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(C) << "\n";
  std::cout << sizeof(C::stack_data) << "\n";
  std::cout << sizeof(C::heap_data) << "\n";
}
```

The problem is that the sizeof(C) is 40 when sizeof stack_data is 32 and sizeof heap_data is 24 due to alignment. I spend extra 8 bytes on one bit field!

I found that moving the flag into structure definitions makes sizes of all three types equal to 32 (without any extra memory for flag)

```
union C {
  struct stack_data {
    bool is_on_stack : 1;
    size_t size : 3;
    int data[(sizeof(std::vector<int>)) / sizeof(int)];
    stack_data() : size(0) {}
  } stack;

  struct heap_data {
    bool is_on_stack : 1;
    std::vector<int> data;
    heap_data() : data() {}
  } heap;
};
```

So I want to know can I be sure that `c.stack_data.is_on_stack` always same with `c.heap_data.is_on_stack`?
And can I always use `stack_data.is_on_stack` even if the actually union in `heap` state without any corruption?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a union for that? How about you try using something like a strategy pattern?

Comment: I try to eliminate heap memory allocation if the container size is less thant 1-2 elements.

If there are very less number of elements I will store them inplace of vector, if there are more, I will construct and initialize a vector with data from array.

This can decrease heap memory allocation and deallocation.
As I know, some std::string implementations use this trick that known as Small String Optimization.

Size of vector is 24 bytes so I can keep 3 ints in its place.
If there are a lot of short vectors and very few longs, this can be some optimization

Comment: Also, as I know, the memory locations of struct members are in same order as they defined.
So I suppose that my bit flag must be in same place for both variants of union but I am not sure.

Comment: As long as there is no access specifier in between, order is guaranteed, yes. I don't know about padding, but since it's the first member it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled the relevant bit:

C++14 standard, chapter 9, point 7:

> M(X) is defined as follows:
>
> - If X is a non-union class type, the set M(X) is empty if X has no non-static data members;
>     otherwise, it consists of the type of the first non-static data member of X (where said member may be an anonymous union), X0, and the elements of M(X0).
> - If X is a union type, the set M(X) is the union of all M(Ui) and the set containing all Ui , where each Ui is the type of the ith non-static
>     data member of X.
> - If X is a non-class type, the set M(X) is empty.
>
> *[ Note: M(X) is the set of the types of all non-base-class subobjects that are guaranteed in a standard-layout class to be at a zero offset in X. — end note ]*

Applying this to your union, assuming I read it well, you get that M(your union) is `stack`, `heap`, `stack.is_on_stack`, `heap.is_on_stack`. That is, all of them are guaranteed to be at 0 offset.

And by the way,I would probable just add a plain `is_on_stack` right into the struct, so you can check which it is *before* you reach into the `union`-ed types. Although technically identical, it would probably be cleaner testing `foo.is_on_stack` rather than `foo.heap.is_on_stack`.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks.
I will keep field in substructures for byte economy however and add getter method to union type.

Comment: Oh it's late I meant right into the *union*:  `union {bool is_on_stack : 1; stack_data stack; heap_data heap;};`. So it exists as `foo.heap.is_on_stack` and `foo.stack.is_on_stack` and `foo.is_on_stack` all the same. You get both byte economy and direct access.

Comment: Thanks for exlanation!